# Save processors results to one Array in MPI

Tags: c++, c, arrays, parallel-processing, mpi

I have a function that is storing some numbers in an array depending on the rank, after finishing I would like to have a bigger array with the result of all processors. 
Lets say I have 4 processors and I'm running my program as the following

```
     mpirun -np 4 storesArrays.out
```

This is my code

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
 MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

int currRank;
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &currRank);

int numRanks;
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numRanks);

int *currArray;
currArray = generateValues(currRank,numRanks);
MPI_Finalize();
}
```

Now I want to create an array that stores `currArray` of each processor. The problem is If I initialize the array in the main, it initialize it every time with each processor.
Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Distribution / gathering of data with MPI is done using `MPI_Scatter` / `MPI_Gather`.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do it:

Use MPI_Gather, which will gather up each processor's data to one "master" processor.

Or, if each processor needs all the processors' arrays, then use MPI_Allgather.